# How can I use SelectComponents to select for components that have a pixel within a certain RGB range within their convex hull?

Tags: image-processing

I calculate a set of morphological components:

```
Components = MorphologicalComponents[Binarize[image,0.1]];
```

We can now use SelectComponents to filter for components satisfying some metric, for example:

```
ChosenComponents = SelectComponents[Components, "Elongation", # <= 0.5 &];
```

However, is there a way to use SelectComponents to select for components that have a pixel within a certain RGB range in their convex hulls?  For example, could we select for only the components that have a pixel with a "red" component of 0.2?

Comment: If you could post a link to an example image, someone with enough rep could upload it to the site and include it in your question.  You might get a better answer with an image that represents your actual problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is to multiply the component numbers in `components` by `1` or `0` according as the corresponding pixel does or does not meet your criterion.  The nonzero elements left over indicate a component that contains a pixel satisfying the criterion.

I couldn't find a good image to use, but I found one that will illustrate the process.

```
image = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Sailboat"}];
```

To me it seems rather complicated...

```
(components = MorphologicalComponents[image, 0.4]) // Colorize
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

...with a lot of components:

```
Max[components]
(* 685 *)
```

Here I had to make up a criterion that suited the image being used.

```
criterion = Function[rgb, rgb[[1]] > 0.7 && rgb[[2]] < 0.5 && rgb[[3]] < 0.5];
critMask = Binarize[image, criterion]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

In the product of the image data arrays, the nonzero entries are the components to be selected, so we delete the zeros and remove duplicate entries.

```
selected = DeleteDuplicates @ DeleteCases[
    Flatten[
      components * ImageData[critMask] ],
    0]
(* {398, 450, 522, 526, 633} *)
```

You can use this list to further process `components`.  For instance, below we replace all the undesired component numbers with `0` and `Colorize` the result.

```
components /. 
  Except[Alternatives @@ selected, _Integer] -> 0 // Colorize
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

One issue is that some of the `critMask` overlaps component `0` in this image.   This may not be a problem in the actual images you have.  If, however, you wish to include component `0` in the selection process, just add `1` to the components.

```
selected = DeleteDuplicates @ DeleteCases[
    Flatten[
     (1 + components) * ImageData[critMask] ],
    0]
(* {1, 399, 451, 523, 527, 634} *)

1 + components /. Except[Alternatives @@ selected, _Integer] -> 0 // Colorize
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]